# How to match just the first number in Regex

Tags: c#, regex, numbers

I have this string

```
<h2 id="1">1. Item 1</h2>
<h2 id="1.2">1.2. Item 1.2</h2>
<h2 id="2">2. Item 2</h2>
```

I need to match headers which have int numbers 1. and 2. in the text. Not 1.2.

I do it like this

```
<h2.*?>(.*?)[0-9]\.\s+(.*?)</h2>
```

It matches all headers. Where am I wrong?

Comment: I think all you need is add an HTML parser and get all `h2` tags with `id` attribute whose value can be parsed as `Integer`.

Comment: Why does he need to add another dependency for just one operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `(.*?)` and then add a `+` after `[0-9]` because `(.*?)` exists before `[0-9]` will match any character zero or more times, which in-turn matches `1.`

```
<h2.*?>[0-9]+\.\s+(.*?)</h2>
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/xD8yU6/1)

Comment: You are right. I just forgot about (.*?), Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the regex:

```
<h[1-6][^>]*>\d{1}\.(?!\d{1}\.)([^<]*)<\/h[1-6]>
```